# How to add an URI scheme to Android TWAs

Tags: android, trusted-web-activity, twa

Is there a way to add an URI scheme for Android TWAs?

I've added my own scheme in our TWA, say for example `<data android:scheme="blah"/>`. However, when I try to access the URI using blah:// when the app had not been launched, it fails to launch the app; It works however when the app has already been launched. Is there a way for us to add a scheme in the TWA that also succeeds on launch?

Comment: Can you add more context on why the URI scheme is being added? https + AppsLinks generally work well with TWAs.

Comment: I've been wanting to try to add another URI scheme other than http and https (let's just say blah://); this is so I would be able to have the TWA app opened from elsewhere. I mean ultimately it does not have to be done by adding an URI scheme, but is there another method of doing so with TWAs?

Comment: Can you paste your AndroidManifest.xml? Also, in this context, does elsewhere mean a web page in the browser or another app?

Comment: The AndroidManifest.xml is based on https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/svgomg-twa
The only change I've made as testing is adding <data android:scheme="blah"/> to the intent-filter, and the behaviour is as mentioned in the question.
For context, this is for the intention of opening from a webpage and another app. If there are ways around to get one for now, we are happy to explore into just that.
Thanks

Comment: You need to add another intent-filter to the Activity. Something like this:     <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category 
                android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category 
                android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data
                android:host="example"
                android:scheme="blah"/>